# how to use Page.getResults in VB.Net for Visio Automation

Tags: vb.net, vb6, visio

Migrating my VB code to VB.net for Visio Automation. I am getting error in Page.GetResults 
"Specified array was not of the expected type".
I guess the Error is with Variant but i could not get resolved.

Thanks for any Help

Answer (score 0):

If you browse the [**sourcecode of this codeplex project**](http://visioautomation.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) you'll find a VB sample for Page.GetResults using Visual Studio 2010. It's in a file called "VS2010_VB_Samples.vb"

I've included the source code below. The example is meant to teach how to use the API. It is not

```
    ' CREATE REQUEST
    Dim request = {
           New With { _
            Key .ID = CShort(shape.ID16), _
            Key .Section = CShort(IVisio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject), _
            Key .Row = CShort(IVisio.VisRowIndices.visRowXFormOut), _
            Key .Cell = CShort(IVisio.VisCellIndices.visXFormWidth), _
            Key .UnitCode = CShort(IVisio.VisUnitCodes.visNoCast) _
           }, 
          New With { _
            Key .ID = CShort(shape.ID16), _
            Key .Section = CShort(IVisio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject), _
            Key .Row = CShort(IVisio.VisRowIndices.visRowXFormOut), _
            Key .Cell = CShort(IVisio.VisCellIndices.visXFormHeight), _
            Key .UnitCode = CShort(IVisio.VisUnitCodes.visNoCast) _
            }
         }

    ' MAP THE REQUEST TO THE STRUCTURES VISIO EXPECTS
    Dim SID_SRCStream = New Short(request.Length * 4 - 1) {}
    Dim unitcodes = New Object(request.Length - 1) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To request.Length - 1
        SID_SRCStream((i * 4) + 0) = request(i).ID
        SID_SRCStream((i * 4) + 1) = request(i).Section
        SID_SRCStream((i * 4) + 2) = request(i).Row
        SID_SRCStream((i * 4) + 3) = request(i).Cell
        unitcodes(i) = request(i).UnitCode
    Next

    ' EXECUTE THE REQUEST
    Dim flags = CShort(IVisio.VisGetSetArgs.visGetFloats)
    Dim results_sa As System.Array = Nothing
    page.GetResults(SID_SRCStream, flags, unitcodes, results_sa)

    ' MAP OUTPUT BACK TO SOMETHING USEFUL 
    Dim results_doubles = New Double(results_sa.Length - 1) {}
    results_sa.CopyTo(results_doubles, 0)

    ' DISPLAY THE INFORMATION
    shape.Text = String.Format("Results={0},{1}", results_doubles(0), results_doubles(1))
```