# How to use Shape.SetFormulas in VB.NET in Visio

Tags: .net, vb.net, visio

The code below gives me an error that says:

> "Specified array was not of the expected type."

```
Sub SetSomeCellValues(ByVal vShape as Shape)
    Dim srcStream as Integer() = {1,1,2,1,1,3}
    Dim theFormulas as Array = {"0"}
    vShape.SetFormulas(srcStream,theFormulas,visGetSetArgs.visSetBlastGuard)
End Sub
```

I have also tried setting `theFormulas` to a `String()` and an `Object()`, but both result in the same error. This works in VBA if `theFormulas` is set to a Variant. I have tried setting `srcStream` to an array as well.

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264803/how-to-use-page-getresults-in-vb-net-for-visio-automation) for a similar issue on stackoverflow, but the answer didn't help.

I would greatly appreciate any help from anyone who has ever gotten the `.SetFormulas`, `.GetFormulas`, or `.GetResults` functions to work in .NET.

Comment: The Vb.Net Short (System.Int16 ) data type is the equivalent of VBA's Integer data type.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft documentation posted [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Visio-VBA/articles/shape-setformulas-method-visio) is for VBA and does explicitly say to use a 2-byte integer, which is the Integer data type in VBA but is a Short or Int16 in .NET. For VB.NET use the following inputs:

`Shape.SetFormulas(SID_SRCStream As Short(),formulaArray As Object(), Flags As visGetSetArg)`